# Переопределение __init__ в метаклассе Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Есть код..

```py
class MyMetaClass(type):  
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr): 
        NewName = name+'new_name'
        attr['new_attr'] = 'new_value'
        NewClass = super().__new__(cls, NewName, bases, attr)      
        return NewClass

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):       
        name = 'TEST'
        attr['new_attr_init'] = 'new_value_init'            
        super().__init__(name, bases, attr)        

class MyClass(metaclass = MyMetaClass):
    MyClassField = 'My_value'
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

obj = MyClass(777)
```

Три вопроса.

1. Почему в метод **__init__** метакласса в качестве аргумента не передается новое имя класса **(name)**, измененное в **__new__**. Переменная **name** после входа в функцию **__init__** такая же, как и при входе в **__new__**. Передаются ссылки на аргументы входа в **__new__**?
2. Почему при изменении, как имени класса, так и атрибутов в методе **__init__** и передаче их в `super().__init__(name, bases, attr)` это не отражается на инициализиции и изменении класса. Атрибут `new_attr_init` со своим значением `new_value_init`  не попадает в словарь инициализированного класса. Такое изменение атрибутов происходит только в **__new__**. А изменить существующий атрибут, например **MyClassField**, можно написав в том же методе **__init__**   `cls.MyClassField = 'New_Value'`, не используя `super().__init__(name, bases, attr)`.
3. Зачем тогда вообще в метаклассах в переопределенном **__init__** и вызывают `super().__init__(name, bases, attr)`, тогда как это не на что не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так надо по идее:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):  
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr): 
        NewName = name+'new_name'
        attr['new_attr'] = 'new_value'
        NewClass = super().__new__(cls, NewName, bases, attr)
        if isinstance(NewClass, cls):
            super().__init__(NewClass, NewName, bases, attr)          
        return NewClass

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):       
        name = 'TEST'
        attr['new_attr_init'] = 'new_value_init'                  

class MyClass(metaclass = MyMetaClass):
    MyClassField = 'My_value'
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

obj = MyClass(777)
```

Comment: В вашем случае метод __init__ не влияет на создание нового атрибута new_attr_init - в классе он не появляется. Также super().__init__(NewClass, NewName, bases, attr) в __new__ тоже ничего не меняет. То есть необходимость super().__init__(NewClass, NewName, bases, attr) - остается неочевидной